# How to convert a int to a numeric char in C#?

Tags: c#, char, int, type-conversion

I wan't to convert a int to a char, but I don't want the `(char)int` method, because `(char)3` won't give `'3'` but `''`.

So, there's a built-in way to get what I want, or I need to make it myself?

Comment: So, you want the character equivalent of 3=>'3', 5=>'5', etc (not the decimal equivalent, e.g. 3=>51, 5=>53, etc.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is the easiest, most readable way:

```
(char)('0' + 3)
```

If you want to be more culture aware, you can use this.

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NativeDigits[3]
```

Comment: Indeed, offset the incoming integer with the "starting point" of the numerics; though this doesn't avoid edge cases.

Comment: Where `3` equals to my int, right?

Comment: @Stefan: Because `System.Convert.ToInt32` doesn't solve the problem, and doesn't even produce a `char`.

Comment: @MisterR.U.B.I: yes.

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work for int's above 9.

Comment: @Stefan: Naturally.  Nothing works for integers above 9, since there is no single character base-10 representation of those numbers.

Comment: Could be converted to char array or even string though. While i'm at it: `3.ToString().ToCharArray()[0]`

Comment: @Stefan:  I see what you mean.  BTW, you can cut out the array.  `3.ToString()[0]`

Comment: It does work, but for some reason not in my code. I need to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: oww nice, again! :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
(char)('0' + IntegerValue)
```

Note: you use 3 so your integer value is 3 you can write 3 instead of integer value

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, from earlier comments (with special thanks to @recursive):

```
int yourInt = 3; //can be double or decimal as well
char val = yourInt.ToString()[0];
```

Although it takes the first digit, it will work for other numeric types as well (double, decimal, ...).